# HTML - Numbers in Select Dropdown Menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML page (index.php) with a drop down menu that contain numbers 1-20. Is there a simpler way of adding the options to the drop down menu rather than just adding each manually like:

```
<option value=1>1</option>
...
<option value=20>20</option>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already mention php in your tags, then using a for-loop when generating the web page would be possible:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=20; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
```

You should further think about spending some more quotes to the value attribute as in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) :

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <=20; $i++) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Such solutions are (at least in my opinion) very hard to read / understand.

Comment: Its a lot easier to indent when included in html files. Makes it easier to read in an ide, as the ide can easily treat the html and php separately. Easier to see where control structures start and stop. Symfony2, and Zend Framework docs even use the alternate syntax for php views. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: His solution is perfectly valid for simplicity's sake... You don't want to include an entire MVC framework or even a templating system for something like this, so the for loop is really the easiest/simplest way aside from just typing out all 20 `option` items.